# UIScrollView not showing up on UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I'm making a simple Sign Up screen for my app. I'm not using `Storyboards` and am doing everything by code. So, to facilitate dynamic scrolling of my view to allow room for the keyboard I'm using the standard Apple practice of embedding my `UITextFields` inside a `UIScrollView`, but they're not showing up at all!

Code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];

    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Register", nil);
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

    // Because Rendering Bug in iOS 7
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    _scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;
    _scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    _scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height * 2);
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    // Personal Image View
    UIButton *profileImageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    profileImageButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80);
    profileImageButton.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, 80);
    [profileImageButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultAvatar"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [profileImageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(uploadImage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_scrollView addSubview:profileImageButton];

    // Username Text Field
    _usernameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    _usernameTextField.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 64);
    _usernameTextField.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, 225);
    _usernameTextField.placeholder = @"\tUsername";
    _usernameTextField.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:244.0f/255.0f green:244.0f/255.0f blue:244.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    _usernameTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:20.0];
    _usernameTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    [_scrollView addSubview:_usernameTextField];

    // Password Text Field
    _passwordTextField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    _passwordTextField.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 64);
    _passwordTextField.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, 320);
    _passwordTextField.placeholder = @"\tPassword";
    _passwordTextField.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:244.0f/255.0f green:244.0f/255.0f blue:244.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    _passwordTextField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:20.0];
    _passwordTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    [_scrollView addSubview:_passwordTextField];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the scrollview declaration with this,

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height * 2);
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Or like this

```
 _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
_scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;
_scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
_scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height * 2);
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

This is because you initialized the "scrollView" and  added "_scrollView" to view.
Also add all subview in the scrollView accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    _scrollView.frame = self.view.frame;
    _scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    _scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height * 2);
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView]; //making mistake here
```

here,you are making mistake you are assigning dynamic property to instance obj and adding local obj as subview...

change this line to [self.view addSubview:scrollView]; 
                 to [self.view addSubview:_scrollView];

and do one thing also alloc init _scrollview.